# app.use got error of Can\'t set headers after they are sent error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my app.js I do this

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){

  if(!req.user){
    res.redirect('/login_');
  }
  next();
})
```

I don't see anything wrong and in route/index.js I do

```
router.get('/login_', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', { user : req.user });
});
```

But I got error of `throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');`
 I know this is caused by the request is not ended but what's wrong with my code above? clueless with this error.

full code of route/index.js http://pastebin.com/kT2QfnjL

Comment: Can you share complete code of yours ? I do not see any mistake in provided code...

Comment: @Rayon thanks for willing to help, attached full code

Comment: I do not see the app.use in the pasetbin?

Comment: @Michael app.use is in app.js

Answer (score 2):

This is caused because when the code tries to send the response after the response is sent.

Reference:

[Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent)

Comment: I know but what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

`return` and redirect to solve this issue

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){

  if(!req.user){
    return res.redirect('/login_');
  }
  next();
})
```